# Apache Flink FileSink in BATCH execution mode: in-progress files are not transitioned to finished state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

**What we are trying to do**: we are evaluating Flink to perform batch processing using [DataStream API in `BATCH` mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/).

**Minimal application to reproduce the issue**:

```java
public class FlinkS3ProcessingDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

        DataStreamSource<String> source = env.readTextFile("file:///Users/user1/any-text-file.txt");

        source.sinkTo(FileSink.forRowFormat(new Path("file:///Users/user1/output/"), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8")).build());

        env.execute("Test Flink application");
    }
}
```

**Flink version**: 1.12.2 or 1.13.0

**Expected result**: "finalized" files in the `/Users/user1/output/` folder.

According to `FileSink` [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/connectors/file_sink.html#general):

> Given that Flink sinks and UDFs in general do not differentiate between normal job termination (e.g. finite input stream) and termination due to failure, upon normal termination of a job, the last in-progress files will not be transitioned to the “finished” state.

specific note for `BATCH` mode:

> Pending files are committed, i.e. transition to Finished state, after the whole input has been processed.

**Actual result**:

```
.
└── 2021-07-13--10
    ├── .part-707a8590-04cb-4c2d-97b2-5652697d9c76-0.inprogress.7e99df6f-703d-44b3-875a-283e12b31c8e
    ├── .part-a82bcabd-065d-4263-bee0-72f8673f3fd3-0.inprogress.65067b75-ef6c-4185-ae87-fe59de95c86a
    ├── .part-c7c36fd5-fb31-4d55-b783-5373ce69e216-0.inprogress.3e953235-09f1-487b-8229-2cdfa0e2daf4
    └── .part-e66b004a-271f-4aae-9604-e035b2c2cfe3-0.inprogress.add8b0d9-aa89-491e-9a9d-f07b73ab8256
```

and the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1046)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:447)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:110)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalRecoverableFsDataOutputStream.getPos(LocalRecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter.getSize(OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.rollingpolicies.DefaultRollingPolicy.shouldRollOnCheckpoint(DefaultRollingPolicy.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.writer.FileWriterBucket.prepareCommit(FileWriterBucket.java:196)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.writer.FileWriter.prepareCommit(FileWriter.java:200)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.sink.AbstractSinkWriterOperator.endInput(AbstractSinkWriterOperator.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.endOperatorInput(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.lambda$close$0(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.closeOperators(OperatorChain.java:439)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.afterInvoke(StreamTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**What we want to know**: if it's possible to use Flink in batch mode in combination with `FileSink` or `StreamingFileSink`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try this with the new `FileSource`? That's the replacement for `readTextFile` with support for BATCH mode execution. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html

Comment: Thanks! Yep, it works as expected with `DataStreamSource<String> source = env.fromSource(FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineFormat(), new Path("file:///Users/user/file.txt")).build(), WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "MySourceName");`. Should I add this as an answer or you'll provide more context why it's like it in your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source interfaces where reworked in [FLIP-27](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface) to provide support for BATCH execution mode in the DataStream API. In order to get the `FileSink` to properly transition PENDING files to FINISHED when running in BATCH mode, you need to use a source that implements FLIP-27, such as the `FileSource` (instead of `readTextFile`): https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html.

As you discovered, that looks like this:

```java
DataStreamSource<String> source = 
  env.fromSource(
    FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(
      new TextLineFormat(),
      new Path("file:///Users/user/file.txt")
    ).build(),
    WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
    "MySourceName"
  );
```

If instead you needed a bulk format, such as parquet, then you would do something more like this:

```java
DataStreamSource<String> source = 
  env.fromSource(
    FileSource.forBulkFileFormat(
      new ParquetColumnarRowInputFormat(...),
      new Path("file:///Users/me/data.parquet")
    ).build(),
    WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
    "MySourceName"
  );
```

For parquet there's also the `ParquetVectorizedInputFormat`, and there are formats for orc, etc.

Comment: Hi David, Would it be the same logic when reading Parquet data? What would be the equivalent of "TextLineFormat" for parquet? and can it be created automatically reading the file's header?

Comment: See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/formats/parquet/ParquetColumnarRowInputFormat.html

Comment: Hi David, I was trying the suggested (using FileSource and FileSink) and the solution was not working for me. It looks like I am missing some conceptual differences and understanding when exactly data would be issued to a file system. Is there some documentation that I can read to understand the mechanics there?

Comment: Data is only finalized to a file system during checkpointing -- having checkpointing enabled is mandatory for streaming jobs using a file sink.

Comment: Though, what about the Batch mode. Here is my usecase. I have tons of historical data. Only now we are starting with streaming processing. The new streaming application will work just fine. But I would like to use the same application and process my historical data from files generating consistent output based on event-time. I thought that File Sink can operate in event-time in Batch mode. However, it looks like that rolling policy works in processing time. Am I right or wrong here?

Comment: I have explicitly set the runtime mode to BATCH and now the files are being finalized! Alright :) that's cool now. Though, looks like the output data is being stored in per-hour folders. That looks like a default bucket assigner.

Comment: In this option how we can add setNestedFileEnumeration(true)?

Answer (score 0):

I could not use above approach because I am reading AVRO files and I could not find AVRO line format.
However it will work ok with env.readTextFile if you assign timestamps and watermarks to input stream like this:

```
public class FlinkS3ProcessingDemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

    DataStream<String> source = env.readTextFile("file:///Users/user1/any-text-file.txt")
                    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                            WatermarkStrategy.<String>noWatermarks().withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public long extractTimestamp(String element, long recordTimestamp) {
                                    return -1;
                                }
                            }));

    source.sinkTo(FileSink.forRowFormat(new Path("file:///Users/artvolk/output/"), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8")).build());

    env.execute("Test Flink application");
}
```

}